# Is it possible for one process (in a multiprocess application) to have read-only access to an object in another process?

Tags: linux, memory, process, parallel-processing, shared-memory

Using a database as an example, if one process has some data in memory, is it possible to give read only access to that data to another process so that queries can be formed?

The access needs to be read-only as the separate processes would never modify the data in any form.

Is it possible for one process to have read-only access to another processes memory (is this dependent on how the processes were forked/spun up)?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  For example, MPI implements *one-sided communication* for just the scenario you describe.  I expect there are many other implementations too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark What is the correct name for it so that I can google more about the subject?

Comment: Well, I call it *one-sided communication* because I'm an MPI user.